# Audio output latency on BASS un4seen on android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, bass

I have been trying to stream mic feed directly from mic to speaker in which i am facing audio latency which varies from device to device.

Following is the code i have tried so far.

The library i am using right now is **BASS un4seen for Android**

```
val rchan = BASS.BASS_RecordStart(
        freq, chans, BASS.BASS_RECORD_PAUSE,
        { handle, _, _, _ ->
            BASSenc.BASS_Encode_IsActive(handle) != 0 // continue recording if encoder is alive
        }, 0
    )
val StreamProc =
        BASS.STREAMPROC { handle, buffer, length, user ->
            BASS.BASS_ChannelGetData(rchan, buffer, length) // get data from the recording stream
        }

    chanPlay = BASS.BASS_StreamCreate(44100, 1, 0, StreamProc, null);
    BASS.BASS_ChannelPlay(chanPlay, false);
    BASS.BASS_ChannelPlay(rchan, false)
```